# MySQL Join each row to every row except itself

Tags: mysql, join

I have a single table that I need to join to itself but each entry needs to be joined to every entry in the table except to itself.

Example:

```
my_table
 tableId  name
 1        John
 2        Dave
 3        Bob
```

Output from join:

```
 tableIdA nameA tableIdB nameB
 1        John  2        Dave
 1        John  3        Bob
 2        Dave  1        John
 2        Dave  3        Bob
 3        Bob   1        John
 3        Bob   2        Dave
```

How would I achieve such an output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` in order to get all combinations. Then use a `WHERE` clause to filter out combinations between the same rows:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS JOIN mytable AS t2
WHERE t1.Id <> t2.ID
```

Comment: If a,b id the same as b,a, then this gets every combination twice.

Comment: @Strawberry I think this is the intention of the OP as well.

Comment: @Strawberry: you are alluding to permutations, whereas OP asked for combinations, as confirmed in their expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross join and eliminate equal rows with where:

```
SELECT
  tbl1.id AS tableIdA,
  tbl1.name AS nameA,
  tbl2.id AS tableIdB,
  tbl2.name AS nameB
FROM
  my_table tbl1,
  my_table tbl2
WHERE
  tbl1.id != tbl2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal INNER JOIN, but specifiy != in the ON clause

```
SELECT a.tableId AS tableIdA ,
        a.name AS nameA ,
        b.tableId AS tableIdB ,
        b.name AS nameB
FROM my_table a
INNER JOIN my_table b
ON a.tableId != b.tableId
```

If you only want each combination once (irrespective of which way round they are) they you can use >

```
SELECT a.tableId AS tableIdA ,
        a.name AS nameA ,
        b.tableId AS tableIdB ,
        b.name AS nameB
FROM my_table a
INNER JOIN my_table b
ON a.tableId > b.tableId
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say:

```
  SELECT tableIdA, nameA, tableIdB, nameB
    FROM ( SELECT tableId AS tableIdA, name AS nameA FROM my_table ) AS A
         NATURAL JOIN
         ( SELECT tableId AS tableIdB, name AS nameB FROM my_table ) AS B
  EXCEPT
  SELECT tableId AS tableIdA, name AS nameA, 
         tableId AS tableIdB, name AS nameB
    FROM my_table;
```

...then I remember mySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`/`MINUS` yet!

This might be one of those rare situation where ye olde `INNER JOIN` looks more attractive?:

```
   SELECT tableIdA, nameA, tableIdB, nameB
    FROM ( SELECT tableId AS tableIdA, name AS nameA FROM my_table ) AS A
         INNER JOIN
         ( SELECT tableId AS tableIdB, name AS nameB FROM my_table ) AS B
         ON tableIdA <> tableIdB;
```